# What does R assume regarding order in paired t-test?

Tags: r, t-test

In the non-formula signature of the `t.test` function `t.test(x, y, paired=T)`, I'm assuming that the data are assumed paired as ordered in the two inputs (x and y in the documentation).

However, in the formula signature `t.test(values ~ groups, df, paired=T)`, how does the function associate observations in the two groups as pairs? By order?

In the reprex below, I create a dataframe with paired before and after data. Then I put it in long form (as would be suitable for the `t.test` function) in two ways: 1) list "before" group in order of observation, then list "after" group in order of observation. 2) list all the data in no particular order.

I run a paired t-test on both data sets. It's pretty obvious that in case 2 the function has absolutely no way of knowing which "after" observation goes with which "before" observation. Can I assume that the `t.test` function understands the data as entered in case 1, that is the "before" and "after" data are both in order of observation?

I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation or any examples online. Because there is no argument for a key that links observations in the two groups, the `t.test` function is making some kind of assumption.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(
  observation = 1:20,
  before = rnorm(20, 10, 2),
  after = rnorm(20, 10.2, 2.3)
)

print.data.frame(df)
#>    observation    before     after
#> 1            1 10.930157 11.818216
#> 2            2 10.870749 10.699232
#> 3            3  9.603120 14.384484
#> 4            4  9.615291  8.777045
#> 5            5  6.714043  9.506421
#> 6            6  9.063117  5.574887
#> 7            7  8.152260 10.357455
#> 8            8  8.256237  8.660646
#> 9            9 12.641977  7.511760
#> 10          10 11.010290  9.391047
#> 11          11 12.545197  9.072856
#> 12          12 12.606526  9.110687
#> 13          13  8.659088 12.445071
#> 14          14  8.958959 10.783168
#> 15          15 11.635443  6.926802
#> 16          16  6.922437 12.419453
#> 17          17 10.326176 10.416757
#> 18          18  7.680960  9.836573
#> 19          19  9.458365  8.083777
#> 20          20  7.235837 12.094290

df_long = 
  df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c("before", "after"),
    names_to = "time", 
    values_to="fabulousness"
  )

print.data.frame(df_long)
#>    observation   time fabulousness
#> 1            1 before    10.930157
#> 2            1  after    11.818216
#> 3            2 before    10.870749
#> 4            2  after    10.699232
#> 5            3 before     9.603120
#> 6            3  after    14.384484
#> 7            4 before     9.615291
#> 8            4  after     8.777045
#> 9            5 before     6.714043
#> 10           5  after     9.506421
#> 11           6 before     9.063117
#> 12           6  after     5.574887
#> 13           7 before     8.152260
#> 14           7  after    10.357455
#> 15           8 before     8.256237
#> 16           8  after     8.660646
#> 17           9 before    12.641977
#> 18           9  after     7.511760
#> 19          10 before    11.010290
#> 20          10  after     9.391047
#> 21          11 before    12.545197
#> 22          11  after     9.072856
#> 23          12 before    12.606526
#> 24          12  after     9.110687
#> 25          13 before     8.659088
#> 26          13  after    12.445071
#> 27          14 before     8.958959
#> 28          14  after    10.783168
#> 29          15 before    11.635443
#> 30          15  after     6.926802
#> 31          16 before     6.922437
#> 32          16  after    12.419453
#> 33          17 before    10.326176
#> 34          17  after    10.416757
#> 35          18 before     7.680960
#> 36          18  after     9.836573
#> 37          19 before     9.458365
#> 38          19  after     8.083777
#> 39          20 before     7.235837
#> 40          20  after    12.094290

df_long_not_paired = 
  df_long %>% 
  arrange(fabulousness)

print.data.frame(df_long_not_paired)
#>    observation   time fabulousness
#> 1            6  after     5.574887
#> 2            5 before     6.714043
#> 3           16 before     6.922437
#> 4           15  after     6.926802
#> 5           20 before     7.235837
#> 6            9  after     7.511760
#> 7           18 before     7.680960
#> 8           19  after     8.083777
#> 9            7 before     8.152260
#> 10           8 before     8.256237
#> 11          13 before     8.659088
#> 12           8  after     8.660646
#> 13           4  after     8.777045
#> 14          14 before     8.958959
#> 15           6 before     9.063117
#> 16          11  after     9.072856
#> 17          12  after     9.110687
#> 18          10  after     9.391047
#> 19          19 before     9.458365
#> 20           5  after     9.506421
#> 21           3 before     9.603120
#> 22           4 before     9.615291
#> 23          18  after     9.836573
#> 24          17 before    10.326176
#> 25           7  after    10.357455
#> 26          17  after    10.416757
#> 27           2  after    10.699232
#> 28          14  after    10.783168
#> 29           2 before    10.870749
#> 30           1 before    10.930157
#> 31          10 before    11.010290
#> 32          15 before    11.635443
#> 33           1  after    11.818216
#> 34          20  after    12.094290
#> 35          16  after    12.419453
#> 36          13  after    12.445071
#> 37          11 before    12.545197
#> 38          12 before    12.606526
#> 39           9 before    12.641977
#> 40           3  after    14.384484

df_long_paired = 
  df_long %>% 
  arrange(desc(time))

print.data.frame(df_long_paired)
#>    observation   time fabulousness
#> 1            1 before    10.930157
#> 2            2 before    10.870749
#> 3            3 before     9.603120
#> 4            4 before     9.615291
#> 5            5 before     6.714043
#> 6            6 before     9.063117
#> 7            7 before     8.152260
#> 8            8 before     8.256237
#> 9            9 before    12.641977
#> 10          10 before    11.010290
#> 11          11 before    12.545197
#> 12          12 before    12.606526
#> 13          13 before     8.659088
#> 14          14 before     8.958959
#> 15          15 before    11.635443
#> 16          16 before     6.922437
#> 17          17 before    10.326176
#> 18          18 before     7.680960
#> 19          19 before     9.458365
#> 20          20 before     7.235837
#> 21           1  after    11.818216
#> 22           2  after    10.699232
#> 23           3  after    14.384484
#> 24           4  after     8.777045
#> 25           5  after     9.506421
#> 26           6  after     5.574887
#> 27           7  after    10.357455
#> 28           8  after     8.660646
#> 29           9  after     7.511760
#> 30          10  after     9.391047
#> 31          11  after     9.072856
#> 32          12  after     9.110687
#> 33          13  after    12.445071
#> 34          14  after    10.783168
#> 35          15  after     6.926802
#> 36          16  after    12.419453
#> 37          17  after    10.416757
#> 38          18  after     9.836573
#> 39          19  after     8.083777
#> 40          20  after    12.094290


df_long_not_paired %>%
  t.test(fabulousness ~ time, ., paired=T)
#> 
#>  Paired t-test
#> 
#> data:  fabulousness by time
#> t = 2.0289, df = 19, p-value = 0.05672
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -0.007878376  0.506318062
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of the differences 
#>               0.2492198

df_long_paired %>% 
  t.test(fabulousness ~ time, ., paired=T)
#> 
#>  Paired t-test
#> 
#> data:  fabulousness by time
#> t = 0.3422, df = 19, p-value = 0.736
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -1.27509  1.77353
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of the differences 
#>               0.2492198
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### NOTE:

When I run this multiple times, I frequently see false positives in the case where I have scrambled the group order.

Comment: It calculates x-y which under the null should have a mean of 0

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying that it assumes group 1 and group 2 are each ordered appropriately. Seems like it would be worth putting that in the docs.

Comment: Pairing implies ordering. Does not seem necessary to state the obvious.

Comment: When using the formula method for `t.test()` the response is split by the grouping factor and passed as variables x and y to the default method.  So yes, there is an assumption that the first observation of factor level 1 corresponds to the first observation of factor level 2 and so on...

Comment: It's not a false positive when you find a difference after scrambling the group order. You specifically generated non-paired data with a difference in the means. For simulating paired data you would do something like `before = rnorm(20, 10, 2)` and then `after = rnorm(1, before + .2, 2)`. Alternatively you could sample from a multivariate normal distribution and specify the correlation before before and after.

Comment: Good point @BrianLang. And this suggests more likelihood of a false negative when scrambled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to find out exactly how this is done, we can look at the source code.

`stats:::t.test.formula` gives us:

> `g <- factor(mf[[-response]])`

where `mf` is the model frame and `response` is the response variable. `g` is then the grouping variable from your formula (LHS).
Then, later, we see the creation of an object `DATA` which is the spliting of `mf` on the basis of the grouping variable `g`. This data is then passed to `stats:::t.test.default` without any changing of the order.

> `DATA <- setNames(split(mf[[response]], g), c("x", "y"))`

We can then look into `stats:::t.test.default`, focusing on wherever `paired` data is mentioned.

> ```
> if (paired) {
>       x <- x - y
>       y <- NULL
>    }
> nx <- length(x)
> mx <- mean(x)
> vx <- var(x)
> ```

From this we see that `t.test.default` simply calculates the difference between pairs and then does a single-sample t-test on the difference.

From all of this together we understand that the order of the observations must be correct in order to have the correct pairs.

Comment: And, apparently, they can be scrambled, as long as the observations in each group are in order. For example: (a1, a2, b1, a3, a4, b2, b3, b4, b5, a5, b6, ...)

Comment: yes, exactly. as long as they are still in order relative to the rest of the group then you'll be all set.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @BrianLang's explanation of the code, the paired test is testing the difference between your samples, and it calculates the difference by the row order. You can verify this by doing:

```
set.seed(111)

df = data.frame(
  observation = 1:20,
  before = rnorm(20, 10, 2),
  after = rnorm(20, 10.2, 2.3)
) 

t.test(x=df$after,y=df$before,paired=TRUE)

    Paired t-test

data:  df$after and df$before
t = 0.30475, df = 19, p-value = 0.7639
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.505079  2.018057
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
              0.2564887
```

If we do it with a long data:

```
df_long = 
  df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c("before", "after"),
    names_to = "time", 
    values_to="fabulousness"
  )

t.test(fabulousness ~ time,paired=TRUE,data=df_long)

    Paired t-test

data:  fabulousness by time
t = 0.30475, df = 19, p-value = 0.7639
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.505079  2.018057
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
              0.2564887
```

I would normally use the first formulation to avoid all these confusion.

Comment: (addressing someone as stupid feels kind of odd), the second approach flows better with piping--which I do a lot of. I see a workaround where I can widen the group column and do something like `df %>% <x and y to columns> %>% t.test(.$x, .$y)`, but I think that's a bit ugly.